# Position independent binary for Atmel SAM Cortex-M0+

Tags: arm, cortex-m, position-independent-code

I am trying to create a position independent binary for a Cortex-M0+ using the ARM GNU toolchain included with Atmel Studio 7 (arm-none-eabi ?).  I have looked many places for information on how to do this, but am not successful. This would facilitate creating ping-pong images in low-high Flash memory areas for OTA updates without needing to know or care whether the update was a ping or pong image for that unit.

I have an 8 kB bootloader resident at 0x0000 which I can communicate with over UART and which will jump to 0x6000 (24 kB) after reset if it detects a binary there (i.e. not 0xFFFF erased Flash).  This SAM-BA bootloader allows me to dump memory and erase and program Flash with .bin files at a designated address.

In the application project (simple LED blink), doing nothing but adding -section-start=.text=0x6000 to the linker command line results in the LED blink code working after it is programmed at 0x6000 by the bootloader. I see also in the hex file that it starts at 0x6000.

In my attempt to create a position independent binary, I have removed the above linker item, and added the -fPIC flag to the command lines for the compiler, the linker and the assembler.  But, I think I still see absolute branch addresses in the disassembly, such as :

28e:   d001        beq.n   294

And the result is that the LED blink binary I load at 0x6000 does not execute unless I specifically tell the linker to put it at 0x6000, which defeats the purpose.  Note that I do also see what looks like relative branches in other parts of the disassembly :

21c:   4b03        ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; (22c )

21e:   58d3        ldr r3, [r2, r3]

220:   9301        str r3, [sp, #4]

222:   4798        blx r3

The SRAM is always at the same address (0x20000000), I just need to be able to re-position the executable.  I have not modified the linker command file, and it does not have section for .got (e.g. *(.got)* or similar).

Can anyone explain to me the specific changes I need to make to the compiler/assembler/linker flags to create a position independent binary in this setup ?  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look more closely at your disassembly. For 0xd001, I get this:

```
 0x00000000:    d001        ..      BEQ      {pc}+0x6 ; 0x6
```

In your case, the toolchain has tried to be helpful. Clearly, a 16 bit opcode can't encode an absolute address with a 32 bit address space. So you are closer than you think to a solution.

Comment: Thanks, I had assumed that the disassembler in Studio was decoding this properly when it says : <system_clock_source_get_hz+0x64>.  system_clock_source_get_hz is the function I pulled the line from, and it didn't occur to me that it could encode an absolute address in a 16-bit opcode.  I need to have another look at this and see if there is a way to debug this in place.  I am interested, by  the way, in how you are able to separate the code line from the rest of the text your response.

Comment: OK, making progress.  I see that the bootloader jumps to the application code, but I notice that the interrupt vector table also no longer has absolute addresses.  With just offsets in the IVT, the application code jumps back into the bootloader instead of jumping to main().  I think there is a vector table relocation register in the M0+ which needs to be written by the bootloader before it jumps to the base of the application IVT.

Comment: It gets better.  The VTOR is being written by the bootloader, but this only affects the address for the IVT entry when an interrupt occurs.  So h/w interrupts will enter the IVT at the right place, but the vector itself is an address that is not properly offset.  With the application at 0x6000, all the IVT entries should be 0x6xxx.  But, with the -fPIC flag, these are instead 0x0xxx, so execution is vectored back randomly into the bootloader.  Since only the bootloader knows where the application code lives, it must modify the just the IVT entries on the fly when it writes the code to Flash.

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track. Vector table is absolute address, so needs to be re-written in this case. Or you can maybe preload the vector table if the ultimate target is always the same.